# Zabbix log monitor will not match totally valid regexes

Tags: regex, zabbix

I created a log item like so:

```
log["/var/log/combined.log","rt=([0-9]+.[0-9][0-9][0-9])"]
```

It is supposed to match strings like:

```
hostname [1.2.3.4]: local1.info/nginx_main:nginx_main [2021-04-12T17:31:46-04:00]: [12/Apr/2021:17:31:46 -0400] "POST /a/b/c/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5 "-" "-" rt=0.041
```

However, the log data never updates. The only one I've been able to get to work is:

```
log["/var/log/combined.log","rt=[0-9.]*"]
```

That, unfortunately, matches a lot more lines than it should.

I've tested this regex in Zabbix's own regex tester in the preprocessor step. It works fine against the source text.

To double check it was running on the agent, I cranked up the debug level and it shows these lines in the agent log:

```
22796:20210412:175306.194 In need_meta_update() key:log["/var/log/combined.log","rt=([0-9]+.[0-9][0-9][0-9])"]
22796:20210412:175306.194 In process_value() key:'hostname:log["/var/log/combined.log","rt=([0-9]+.[0-9][0-9][0-9])"]' lastlogsize:385243596 value:'(null)'
```

That `value:'(null)'` is telling. It's obviously got the right regex, but it'll never match a line.

Now, I do have several other items monitoring this log file. I went ahead and disabled them to see if perhaps contention was the problem. Unfortunately, that resulted in no change to the situation. I'm honestly out of ideas.

I'm using Zabbix version 4.4.10 on CentOS 7.7.